# Python multiprocessing: reduce during map?

Tags: python, mapreduce, multiprocessing, pool

Is there a way to reduce memory consumption when working with Python's `pool.map`?

To give a short example: `worker()` does some heavy lifting and returns a larger array...

```
def worker():
    # cpu time intensive tasks
    return large_array
```

...and a Pool maps over some large sequence:

```
with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as p:
    result = p.map(worker, large_sequence)
```

Considering this setup, obviously, `result` will allocate a large portion of the system's memory. However, the final operation on the result is:

```
    final_result = np.sum(result, axis=0)
```

Thus, `NumPy` effectively does nothing else than reducing with a sum operation on the iterable:

```
    final_result = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, result)
```

This, of course, would make it possible to consume results of `pool.map` as they come in and garbage-collecting them after reducing to eliminate the need of storing all the values first.

I could write some `mp.queue` now where results go into and then write some queue-consuming worker that sums up the results but this would (1) require significantly more lines of code and (2) feel like a (potentially slower) hack-around to me rather than clean code.

Is there a way to reduce results returned by a `mp.Pool` operation directly as they come in?

Comment: Without seeing the job you're actually trying to do, I'm pretty much inclined to think that you should be looking into vectorizing that rather than pooling the work

Comment: @roganjosh yes, vectorizing should, of course, always be preferred due to the heavy-lifting then being executed "deep-down" in NumPy directly. However, although my `worker` finally returns a NumPy array in the end, the work itself unfortunately is not vectorizable.

Comment: Why not let every worker return a subtotal instead of the large_array and only sum these subtotals in the parent?

Comment: @Darkonaut the result, in the end, is a 2D distribution over the whole array. Thus, the spatial relation is important. The sum will not reduce the whole array but actually sum-up the arrays element-wise (and I need the element-wise result in the end).

Comment: `.imap_unordered()` would let you handle the results arrays as they come in.

Answer (score 0):

The iterator mappers `imap` and `imap_unordered` seem to do the trick:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

def worker( a ):
    # cpu time intensive tasks
    large_array = np.ones((20,30))+a
    return large_array


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    arraysum = np.zeros((20,30))
    large_sequence = range(20)
    num_cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()    
    
    with multiprocessing.Pool( processes=num_cpus ) as p:
        for large_array in p.imap_unordered( worker, large_sequence ):
            arraysum += large_array
```